# has_many and belongs_to association with join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I have a Persons table and a Notifications table.

There are lots of people and 6 notifications that each can potential receive.

I'm thinking of having a Notifications table with just:
'id'
'notifitcation_name'

But each person can change certain characteristics about each notification.

then I'd have a join table with

'person_id'
'notification_id'
'notification_text'

Does that seem appropriate?

Then Person has_many Notifications and Notification belongs_to Person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, with a few small changes.

I would create a `NotificationType`, which contains the 6 possible notifications a person could receive. And then you have the `Notification` which links the `NotificationType` to the `Person` with an actual message.

So your tables would look something like

```
Person: id, name, ...
NotificationType: id, name, severity, ...
Notification: id, person_id, notification_type_id, message
```

and your models would be

```
class NotificationType
  has_many :notifications
end

class Person
  has_many :notifications
end

class Notification
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :notification_type
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) association.

**EDIT**:
This actually probably isn't what you want. I misunderstood you when you said "join table". You should have a Persons table and a Notifications table and Person has many Notifications and Notification belongs to Person as you said. But in the Notifications table just store what you said to put in the join table: `notification_id`, `person_id`, `notification_text`, and any other attributes the notification needs to have.

Comment: But where would I put the notification settings specific to a person, such as their modified notification text?

Comment: Please see my edited answer and comment if you have further questions.

Comment: That would work, but my concern is if I change the name of one of the notifications then I have to change all the records in the notification table with that name, not just the one record. Or if the notifications get more attributes that aren't specific to an individual. For example, I could have a notification that is called 'reminder', and it has an attribute 'advance_time' that would take a value which is the number of hours before an event that the reminder gets sent. Then I'd again have to change a bunch of records and not just one. Make sense?

Comment: Then you need to create a different model `NotificationType` to store the different types of notifications. Then NotificationType has many Notifications and Notification belongs to NotificationType. And add a `notification_type_id` column to your notifications table.